# How put item in shelf using Recycler-View

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a picture that has a set of shelves. we want to put all three items on a shelf as shown in the picture.

picture : [this first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8rDR.jpg)

I have trying in this code

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/rec"
 android:background="@drawable/boo"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

[this is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbk7C.png)

this is my code in MainActivity :

```
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager= new GridLayoutManager(this,3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

item card of recyclerview :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/txt_number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_number"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="why are you here"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: i shared my code see it @FrancescoBocci